# How to get android and IOS device token in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms, token

I need the both tokens...I am using PushNotification Plugin...I know its return the token...but i think the documentation is very bad...I dont need to show a notification...I ONLY need the tokens...ONLY IT 
Can someone save me??? I really need it. Do I need some configuration in app developer?
I've already got the sender id for android and I initialized the plugin in both: AppDelegate and MainActivity
Help PLEEEAAAAAAASE

My class in pcl

```
using PushNotification.Plugin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using PushNotification.Plugin.Abstractions;

namespace neoFly_Montana
{
public class PushNot : IPushNotificationListener
{
    public void OnError(string message, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnMessage(JObject values, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }

    public void OnRegistered(string token, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnUnregistered(DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool ShouldShowNotification()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Joyce! I don't recommend using the PushNotificationPlugin. You don't gain much from the abstraction and it's pretty easy to add the code to handle the push notification without it. A better tool is the Mobile Center Push SDK, https://mobile.azure.com. Mobile Center made managing push notifications super easy.

Answer (score 1):

Both Google and Apple will send you the token in the `OnRegistered` method once the device has been registered with APNS or GCM/FCM.

In `OnRegistered` you can add logic to save the token.

```
public void OnRegistered(string token, DeviceType deviceType)
{
    //use token here
}
```

Comment: yeah..I Know it...
I am using the line CrossPushNotification.Current.Register(); in order to try call it...but I am having a unhandle exception...i dont know the caus

Comment: That’s no fun. Edit the question and post the error / stacktrace and I’ll take a look!

Comment: where can I see the cause of a unhandled exception? my try catch is not gettint it...

Comment: i think maybe the problem is the android sender id...but I only need to confirm it

Comment: in ios there isnt an exception and when the app initializes there is a message to permit push notification...but, it also don't call the onregistered method...

Comment: It's great that they call an override in no particular order. But my authentication completes before that method is called, which is the trigger to set up push notifications (and background services). How can I manually get it?